# Java Access Denied Printing to Receipt Printer on Windows 7

Tags: java, printing, windows-7, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

I developed a Java POS system about 11 years ago that currently still runs on Windows XP and Vista machines.  I am in the process of updating them to Windows 7 and now having issues printing to the Star Micronics Thermal Receipt Printers.

Here is the line of the code that works just fine in Windows XP and Vista machines when they are accessing shared printers on other machines on the network but I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access Denied)` when I try to print on a printer attached to a Windows 7 box.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("\\\\machine1\\printer");
```

Now in this scenario machine2 (doesn't matter if it is Windows XP, Vista, or 7) is trying to print on a receipt printer attached to machine1 (Windows 7) through my Java program.  If I try to print a normal text file from Notepad from machine2 on machine1 it works fine.  It is only through my Java on the line mentioned above does this fail.  Once again if machine1 and machine2 are either Windows XP or Vista then there is no issue and this has worked for 11 years.

I believe it has to be a permissions issue with Windows 7 but I am not sure what it is.  Remember the second machine can see the printer on the Windows 7 machine and even print on it.  It is only through my java program where this fails.  I could try rewriting my old code on how I print but I am afraid I will run into similar problems.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue today, after upgrading to people that had Windows XP computers with printing working, to Windows 7 computers. I couldn't even "echo test > \machine1\GenericT", got Access is Denied.

I found that you need to provide Security access to printers folder located in "C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS", you should add "Everyone" and give it Modify. This is you will be able to print no problem.

Comment: In my case, the modify permission is not necessary. The write permission is enough. Thanks for the answer, saved me hours of trying.